# How to create a long service column in PowerBi?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have a table of colleagues which includes their start date at company. I want to create a table that will show colleagues that have achieved 5, 10, 15, 20 (etc up to 70) years service in that week. Is there a formula I can use in a column on the table that will return all colleagues that have achieved a milestone in the current week?

FOR EXAMPLE
Current data - Colleague name: Joe Bloggs
Start Date: 25/10/2017
Colleague name: Jane Doe
Start Date: 23/10/2002

What I need: Long Service Colleagues -
Joe Bloggs - 5 years
Jane Doe - 20 years

Comment: if you want a fast answer, add sample dummy data and expected result accordingly...

Comment: Yes, there is. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then **edit your question** to provide sufficient information so we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your employee start date is in B2

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1)-YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))>=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1,DATE(YEAR(B2)+YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1)-YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1+7),   YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1)-YEAR(B2)&" TW",0)
```

This will return the number of years being acheived that week followed by TW "5 TW", if not will return 0